# Let $T(z)=\frac{a_1z + b_1}{c_1z+d_1}$ $S(z)=\frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$ be two Mobius transformations. Show that if ...

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, problem-solving, mobius-transformation

> Let $T(z)=\frac{a_1z + b_1}{c_1z+d_1}$ $S(z)=\frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$ be two Mobius transformations. Show that if $T = S$, then there is $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $a_1 = \lambda a_2, b_1= \lambda b_2, c_1 = \lambda c_2, d_1 = \lambda d_2$.

$\frac{a_1z + b_1}{c_1z+d_1} \leftrightarrow c_1z^2 +(d_1 - a_1)z + b_1$

$\frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2} \leftrightarrow c_2z^2 +(d_2 - a_2)z + b_2 = 0$

$c_1z^2 +(d_1 - a_1)z + b_1 = c_2z^2 +(d_2 - a_2)z + b_2 = 0$

$c_1 = 1 c_2 $

$b_1 = 1 b_2 $

$d_1 - a_1 = d_2 - a_2 \to a_1 = d_1 = 1 a_2 = 1 d_2$.

This must not be right because it's too simple, but it was the only idea I had.

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Can you explain the lines with $\leftrightarrow$ in them? On the left is an expression, on the right is another expression (in the first line) or an equation (in the second line). It is not clear what these are trying to say to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is nice, but you do not carry it out properly.

Each Möbius transformation $T$ has the form $T(z) = \dfrac{az + b}{cz + d}$ with a matrix $M  = \left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right)$ such that $\det M = ad -  bc \ne 0$. Let us write $T = \theta_M$. Note that $\det M \ne 0$ implies

1. If $a = 0$, then $b, c \ne 0$.
2. If $b = 0$, then $a, d \ne 0$.

Given $M_i = \left(\begin{matrix}a_i & b_i \\ c_i & d_i\end{matrix}\right)$, we are expected to prove that $\theta_{M_1} = \theta_{M_2}$ implies $M_1 =  \lambda M_2$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. Note that in this case automatically $\lambda \ne 0$ (otherwise $M_1 = 0$ and $\det M_1 = 0$).

$\theta_{M_1} = \theta_{M_2}$  means that for all $z$
$$(a_1z + b_1)(c_2z +d_2)  = (a_2z + b_2)(c_1z +d_1) ,$$
i.e.
$$a_1c_2z^2 + (a_1d_2 +b_1c_2)z + b_1d_2 = a_2c_1z^2 + (a_2d_1 +b_2c_1)z + b_2d_1 .$$
This gives the three equations
$$a_1c_2 = a_2c_1 \tag{1} $$
$$a_1d_2 +b_1c_2 = a_2d_1 +b_2c_1 \tag{2}$$
$$b_1d_2 = b_2d_1 \tag{3}$$

Case 1: $a_2 = 0$.
By 1. we see that $b_2, c_2 \ne 0$. Thus $ \lambda = b_1/b_2$ is a well-defined complex number and $(1)$ shows that $a_1 = 0$. By definition $b_1 = \lambda b_2$. From $(2)$ we get $c_1 =  (b_1/b_2) \cdot c_2 = \lambda c_2$ and similarly from $(3)$ $d_1 = \lambda d_2$. Trivially $a_1 = \lambda a_2$.

Case 2: $b_2 = 0$.
Analogous as Case 1. Explicitly, from 2. we conclude that $a_2,d_2 \ne 0$. Thus $ \lambda = a_1/a_2$ is a well-defined complex number and $(3)$ shows that $b_1 = 0$. By definition $a_1 = \lambda a_2$. From $(2)$ we get $d_1 =  (a_1/a_2) \cdot d_2 = \lambda d_2$ and similarly from $(1)$ $c_1 = \lambda c_2$. Trivially $b_1 = \lambda b_2$.

Case 3: $a_2, b_2 \ne 0$.
Then $\lambda = a_1/a_2$ and $\mu = b_1/b_2$ are well-defined complex numbers. This means that $a_1 = \lambda a_2$ and $b_1 = \mu b_2$ and from $(1), (3)$ we get $c_1 = \lambda c_2$ and $d_1 = \mu d_2$. Inserting in $(2)$ gives
$$\lambda(a_2d_2 - c_2b_2) = \mu(a_2d_2 - c_2b_2) .$$
Since the second factor is $\ne 0$, we see that $\lambda = \mu$.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2$ all non-null to keep the answer short: these have to be dealt with in a few separate cases).

You can use specific values for $z$:

- $z=0$ gives $b_1/d_1=b_2/d_2$
- $z\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $a_1/c_1=a_2/c_2$
- $z=-b_1/a_1$ (zero) gives $a_2/a_1=b_2/b_1$
- (as an alternative to any of the 3 previous lines) $z\rightarrow -d_1/c_1$ (pole) gives $c_2/c_1=d_2/d_1$

So posing $a_1/a_2=\lambda$, we get
$\lambda=c_1/c_2=b_1/b_2=d_1/d_2$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid calculation: You could use that to all Möbius transformations $T(z) = \frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1}$ and $S(z) = \frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$, there exist unique classes $[A_T],[A_S]\in GL(2)/\mathbb{C}^*$, with  representatives given by \begin{align*}
A_T &= \left(\begin{matrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1\end{matrix}\right),\\
A_S &=\left(\begin{matrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2\end{matrix}\right),
\end{align*}
so that that $$[A_T\cdot A_S] = [A_{T\circ S}].$$ Here, $\mathbb{C}^*:=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ has to be factured out, because multiplying such a matrix by any non-zero $\lambda$ would yield another matrix with the same property (just as multiplying each coefficient $a,b,c,d$ in in the initial Möbius-function would do).

Then, assuming that $T=S$, you would get $E_2 = A_T\cdot A_T^{-1} \equiv A_T\cdot A_S^{-1} \mod \mathbb{C}^*$, which is equivalent to $A_T \equiv A_S \mod \mathbb{C}^*$, i.e. $A_T = \lambda\cdot A_S$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^*$.